# Prime number and Relationship of Sequences of period 4,5,and 6

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, trigonometry, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be a prime number.($p \neq 2,3,5$)

Let $t^+,t^-,a$ be sequences.
$t^+_{k+5}=t^+_k,t^+_1=0,t^+_2=-1,t^+_3=-1,t^+_4=0,t^+_5=2$
$t^-_{k+5}=t^-_k,t^-_1=-1,t^-_2=0,t^-_3=0,t^-_4=-1,t^-_5=2$
$a_k=2(\cos\frac{k}{3}\pi-\cos\frac{k}{2}\pi)$

Then,
case $p\equiv1,4\pmod5$
$\underset{1\leq k\leq{p-1}}{\sum}\frac{a_k t^+_{p-k}}{k}\equiv0\pmod p$

case $p\equiv2,3\pmod5$
$\underset{1\leq k\leq{p-1}}{\sum}\frac{a_k t^-_{p-k}}{k}\equiv0\pmod p$

I have checked this for $p<10000$.
Can anyone prove this?

Note
$t^+_k-t^-_k=(\frac{k}{5})$
$t^+_k+t^-_k=e^{\frac{2}{5}k\pi i}+e^{\frac{4}{5}k\pi i}+e^{\frac{6}{5}k\pi i}+e^{\frac{8}{5}k\pi i}$

Comment: why do you use this notation ($t^+$, $t^-$) for your sequences? Why do you not use to different letters?

Comment: Sorry. There is no particular meaning.

Comment: from where do you have this sequence?

Comment: In research on Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: does k index only primes or index all positive integers

Comment: $t^{+}_{7}-t^{-}_{7}=-1-(0)=-1 \ne 7/5$

Comment: This is a very interesting conjecture. I wonder if it might be easier to approach this problem from the Fibonacci series ideas which led to this result. How did the $\frac{1}{k}$ terms arise?

Comment: Please check my other questions.